# Send email notification for the new created survey using webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm looking for a way to send email notification to all my users once my scheduled survey is already open. Upon checking the Webform module, all I can see about email notification is when a user submitted a response to the surey.

Comment: This is for D8.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms does not work that way.  Webforms is for you or an administrator to receive an email when a user on your site fills out a form.

For example, if a customer wants you to send them a brochure in the mail, Webforms will let you know when they fill out your form.

If you want to notify multiple site users (not administrators) about a form being available, consider trying something like MailChimp, or one of the other popular mailing list programs.  The well-known ones (MailChimp, Constant Contact, etc.) all have modules that will allow you to integrate them with your Drupal web site.

Comment: What I'm doing is a satisfactory survey for a company. Wherein everytime HR created a survey. CRON will handle the automatic sending of email notification to all employees about the survey that they need to answer. Anyway I already created a solution from this. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: Okay.  Sorry I misunderstood the needs of your application.  Cron can be used to trigger Rules that can send email.  I would have suggested [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) to load content for the Rule to process, but that module hasn't been ported to Drupal 8 yet.